# Can services be represented like aggregation relationship in UML?

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation, class-diagram

There is service java class which uses another service class internally. They are completely independent classes of each other. They are simple Spring beans:

```
public class Service1 {
  ...
}

public class Service2 {
  @Bean
  private Service1 service1;
  ...
}
```

I want to create UML diagram where they are shown. I want to show relationship between them. Is it a best or normal practice to show relationships of such classes like aggregation? Is it correct to do so?

[image: Aggregation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My famous citation of p. 110 UML 2.5

> **shared** | Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

So, go ahead. Use it, but document it. Or use a simple association. I'd prefer the latter.

Comment: Yes! I vote for the simple association as well.  I do not see an aggregation semantic between these classes.